# indexOf comparing two lists, not matching exact values

Tags: arrays, angular, indexof

Alright, so i have a list of checkmark forms, and upon clicking them, i submit an event and put all checked boxes values into a list, i then compare that list with another list to changes the matching checked values from true to false (using index of).

when i click canada, my console prints the expected output (Canada is true, United States and Mexico are false),
but then i click Mexico, so now Canada and Mexico have been selected, and all my countries turn to false.

[image]

i'm wondering if this is a problem with the way i'm implenting index of, or is it the order of calling functions that is causing this? a checked box should return true.

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-geo-drop',
    templateUrl: './geo-drop.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./geo-drop.component.css']
})

export class GeoDropComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedItems: any [] = [];

    places = [
        { code: 'US', allow: 'true', name: 'United States', continent: 'North America' },
        { code: 'CA', allow: 'true', name: 'Canada', continent: 'North America' },
        { code: 'MX', allow: 'false', name: 'Mexico', continent: 'North America' }
    ];

    countriesForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // add checkbox for each country
        this.countriesForm = new FormGroup({});
        for (let i = 0; i < this.places.length; i++) {
            this.countriesForm.addControl(
                this.places[i].name, new FormControl(false)
            )
        }
    }

    allow(selectedPlaces: Array<any>, allPlaces: Array<any>) {

        allPlaces.filter(function (place) {
            if (place.name.indexOf(selectedPlaces) > -1) {
                place.allow = true;
            } else {
                place.allow = false;
            };
        });
        this.places.forEach(item => {
            console.log(item.name, item.allow);
        });
    }

    search(place, event) {

        let index = this.selectedItems.indexOf(place.name);
        if (event.target.checked) {
            if (index === -1) {
                this.selectedItems.push(place.name);
                console.log(this.selectedItems);
            }
        } else {
            if (index !== -1) {
                this.selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
                console.log(this.selectedItems);
            }
        }
        this.allow(this.selectedItems, this.places);
    }
}
```

html

```
<div class="geo-list">
    <div class="content-box container">
         <form [formGroup]="countriesForm">
            <div class="place" *ngFor="let place of places">
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    formControlName="{{place.name}}"
                    (change)="search(place, $event)"
                >
                {{ place.name }} | {{ place.code }} | {{ place.continent }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm starting to think this could be because my onInit function does not match the checkboxes with the current values from my places list. but, my allow function runs through and handles that, so shouldnt it change the values right away? or should i call the allow function in my onInit function?

Comment: As a side note, maybe there is a way to pass that true and false value directly from the form to the places list and vice versa? like, making the box checks = true, and submitting that data back. as well as initializing the checkboxes with the correct checks. still working on it, but any ideas, let me know

Comment: UPDATE i added [checked]="{{place.allow}}" to update this list of checkboxes. this added some even weirder behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution. though i don't believe it's the fastest, if a faster method is known, please post it. this method changes the value directly on every (change), and then binds the checkbox to the current value of allowed

comp.

```
export class GeoDropComponent implements OnInit {

    places = [
        { code: 'US', allow: true, name: 'United States', continent: 'North America' },
        { code: 'CA', allow: true, name: 'Canada', continent: 'North America' },
        { code: 'MX', allow: false, name: 'Mexico', continent: 'North America' }
    ];

    countriesForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() { }

    // use ng on destroy to send final copy?

    ngOnInit() {
        // add checkbox for each country
        this.countriesForm = new FormGroup({});
        for (let i = 0; i < this.places.length; i++) {
            this.countriesForm.addControl(
                this.places[i].name, new FormControl(false)
            )
        }
    }

    search(place, event) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.places.length; i++) {
            if (this.places[i].name === place.name) {
                this.places[i].allow === true ? this.places[i].allow = false : this.places[i].allow = true;
            }
        }
        console.log(place.allow);
        console.log(this.places);
    }
}
```

html

```
<input
                    type="checkbox"
                    formControlName="{{place.name}}"
                    value="{{place.allow}}"
                    (change)="search(place, $event)"
                    [checked]="place.allow"
                >
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your own debug info; you're asking the index of "Canada, Mexico"
Since none of your countries are called "Canada, Mexico", they're false.

You need to loop through all selected boxes in your html to fix it.

Comment: so you are saying that the filter function is not the one to use here? i should just directly use a for loop? i'm trying not to do that, since this list is going to be very large when finished. it needs to parse quickly, suggestions?

Comment: @FussinHussin 1. I'm not stating anything about the filter function, I'm simply explaining why your debug values are false. You can see in your picture that value (2) is 'Canada, Mexico' rather than 'Mexico' and thus does not meet any other value in your predefined list. As for your other statement: I'm not that familiar with Angular, but if you quickly need to exclude a list from another list, look into `Except` (filters out anything in this list that already occurs in other list.)

Comment: right okay, i'm just trying to figure out how to compare canada and mexico as separate values. im not finding anything on google for except. got a link?

Comment: Any ideas on a fast and better way to compare these lists would be appreciated

Comment: using `const matchingPlace =  this.place.find(p => p.name === place.name); if(matchingPlace) { matchingPlace.allow = !matchingPlace.allow }` would be idiomatic and readable. Why are you trying to optimize? Have you benchmarked?